# Get Guid with query string

Tags: asp.net, guid

I get a Guid value in a variable like that

```
var getvalueGuid = db.Clients.Where(u => u.Numero_telephone == 
TextBox_numero_telephone.Text).Select(u => u.GuID).FirstOrDefault();
```

And i would like to convert it in a query string like  that:

```
getvalueGuid = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

How to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Guid.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Guid getvalueGuid;
if(Guid.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out getvalueGuid))
{
    // successfully parsed 
}
```

Comment: In fact, i neet to pass it in a mail body like that:             string body = "<p>" + "Bonjour," + " <p> " + "vous venez de modifier vos notifications e-mail pour le logiciel : " + DropDownList_choixlogiciel.SelectedValue + "<p>" + "Vous avez choisi de recevoir les newsletters concernant le(s) groupe(s) : " + " <br> - " + stringAbonnements +

                           "<p>" + "<p>" + "Veuillez confirmer vos choix : " + getvalueGuid +  "<p>" + "Cordialement, L'équipe Septeo .";

Comment: @user3711519: and what is the problem? `getvalueGuid` is initialized in the `if`.

Comment: I make that var getvalue = db.Clients.Where(u => u.Numero_telephone == TextBox_numero_telephone.Text).Select(u => u.GuID).FirstOrDefault();

            Guid getvalueGuid;
            if (Guid.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out getvalueGuid))
            {
                getvalue = getvalueGuid;
            }

Comment: @user3711519: what means "it doesn't work"? Why do you select a guid, just to assign a different one in the next line anyway? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve and what didn't work. Why do you need `getvalue = getvalueGuid;`?

Comment: I would like to get the Guid variable in the body mail and then, when the user will click on the link (the guid), a new aspx page will apear

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get that inside a QueryString, only if you're having the url like

> www.example.com/page?id=[guid_here]

Then when you'll use the code, it would provide you with a String which would contain the Query String provided in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your question as you're missing a lot of detail, but I think you want to get a strongly-typed GUID value from the querystring?

`System.Guid` doesn't have a `TryParse` method, so you'll have to use the constructor and catch any exceptions thrown:

If so, then do this:

```
String guidStr = Request.QueryString["id"];
Guid guid = null;
try {
    guid = new Guid( guidStr );
} catch(ArgumentNullException) {
} catch(FormatException) {
} catch(OverflowException) {
}

if( guid == null { 
    // Inform user that the GUID specified was not valid.
}
```

The three exceptions (`ArgumentNullException`, `FormatException`, and `OverflowException` are documented in the notes for the `Guid(String)` constructor here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

#### Update:

I forgot that .NET 4.0 introduced the `TryParse` method. Use that instead if you're using .NET 4.0 or later: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Guid requestGuid;
if (Guid.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out requestGuid))
{
   // Do logic here with requestGuid
}
```